# FTPES and ExactTarget File Exports

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are setting up a new vsftpd server to use FTPES. We setup a file location in ExactTarget specifying this new FTPS location. When we try to run a job to send files from ET to our FTP server it will fail on the file transfer. We can see a file but it is zero bytes. Now, if we change the file location in ET from FTPS to FTP, the file will show up properly on our server.

We can actually connect to the server directly with our local clients via FTPES and transfer files without incident.

For testing purposes we have shutdown iptables on the server, set up PASV in vsftpd and opened up a big hole in the firewall.

Any suggestions on how ET wants things to be setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is true why does ExactTarget provide FTPS options in its admin tool?

Here are the docs relating to FTPS
http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/admin/file_transfer_location/

What is not clear is how they are performing the connection. We think it is explicit after using wireshark. We think it must be some PORT issue on the data side of the connection.

UPDATE:
I have found you need to explicitly set require_ssl_reuse=NO and session_support=NO in the vsftpd config. In CentOS yum install it was compiled with these options defaulting to YES. For ET to work they needed to be set to NO.

Comment: The information I received was clearly incorrect - glad you got it working!

Comment: Thanks! It was frustrating since I had no error logs from ET and the VSFTPD was not giving up much either.

Comment: This is a recurring theme, and even internally we occasionally scratch our heads.  It usually turns out to be a firewall problem.